# Regexp for decimal positive/ negative numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having such string:
**(Reasoncode1 -49.00)**

From that string I need to take all the decimal values both positive/ negative so --> -49.00
I've created such regexp: `-?\d+\.*\d*`
It work but if the string has number inside like: "Reasoncode**1**" then it takes that one value and I want to avoid it.

Comment: You can use: `-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: Why not use `Decimal.TryParse`?

Comment: This really depends on your target inputs generally. Pranjal Patel's solution works, but if there's some input like `Reasoncode1.0 -49.00` then similar issue happens. If there isn't then you can choose that solution as correct answer. If they all follow `string number` format, you can also consider `.Split()` and take the 2nd element for TryParse.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex

```
-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```